# Object Error when using set on an variable

Tags: excel, vba

The object Error keeps appearing no matter what I try. I'm not that experienced in VBA.

Its appears to be when I'm giving the "lastrow" variable a value.

```
Const sFILE_PATH    As String = "C:\Users\Downloads\"
Const sEXTENSION    As String = ".xlsm"

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow_Offset As Long: lastrow_Offset = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sFileName As String

sFileName = "2018-12"
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(sFILE_PATH & sFileName & sEXTENSION)

Set lastrow = wbk.Sheets("Acc").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Remove the `Set` command before populating the variable. The command `.row` returns a number, not a range.

Comment: I would break the last statement into different statements and see which one fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `Dim lastrow As Long` so it's not an object which needs to be `Set`.  It's a variable that needs to be assigned

```
lastrow = wbk.Sheets("Acc").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
```

I haven't tested this against your implied workbook structure but assume `wbk.Sheets("Acc").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row` evaluates to a `Long`